# FFMPEG-PHP Error "Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container."

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Am using FFMPEG installed on a Windows server. I have a PHP webpage that uploads and trims videos using FFMPEG, when I upload MP4's with AAC audio, especially videos over 100mb, I get the following errors in the log output below.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to getting this resolved.

Log output of the error below:

```
<pre>object(FFMpeg\Exception\RuntimeException)#35 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(15) "Encoding failed"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(108) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ffmpeg-lib\ffmpeg-php\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\Media\AbstractVideo.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(106)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(45) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ffmpeg-lib\process.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(35)
      ["function"]=>
      string(4) "save"
      ["class"]=>
      string(26) "FFMpeg\Media\AbstractVideo"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException)#43 (9) {
    ["command":protected]=>
    string(393) "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -ss 00:00:17.00 -i "temp/temp_20201110-100656_1080p-220mb.mp4" -t 00:00:52.00 -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:v 1000k -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -pass 1 -passlogfile "W:/TempIIS\ffmpeg-passes5fabd8bdf3612uvd6b/pass-5fabd8bdf378b" "temp/20201111-122741.mp4""
    ["errorOutput":protected]=>
    string(830102) "ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'temp/temp_20201110-100656_1080p-220mb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 19529854
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2016-04-11T06:32:53.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:25.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13772 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-04-11T06:32:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 13639 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-04-11T06:32:53.000000Z
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Invalid NAL unit size (-360624822 > 108076).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 2.15 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Invalid NAL unit size (1926587749 > 39711).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Invalid NAL unit size (-1483385910 > 21666).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Invalid NAL unit size (1060193647 > 41388).
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad22e80] Invalid NAL unit size (1499431567 > 26513).
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad22e80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Invalid NAL unit size (-23485766 > 46738).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Invalid NAL unit size (2023411154 > 21613).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Invalid NAL unit size (519125029 > 48521).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Invalid NAL unit size (-2099015076 > 25631).
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad22e80] Invalid NAL unit size (-1081182476 > 46590).
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad22e80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 2.0 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Multiple frames in a packet.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Invalid NAL unit size (-2080403149 > 27914).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3dac80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 3.9 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 2.6 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Number of scalefactor bands in group (52) exceeds limit (49).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 3.10 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 2.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 3.8 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] channel element 3.9 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Number of bands (50) exceeds limit (49).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Number of bands (17) exceeds limit (13).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 000001fc5a9ce8c0] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Invalid NAL unit size (-296706614 > 48346).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3be480] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Invalid NAL unit size (-1419758286 > 23497).
[h264 @ 000001fc5a3e4540] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Invalid NAL unit size (86578229 > 53255).
[h264 @ 000001fc5ad06500] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

Comment: Are you sure the input file isn't corrupted somehow? What do you get when you run ffmpeg on the command line? Have you tried to match the actual audio bitrate of the video to your command line config?

Comment: I can confirm the video file is not corrupted, Ive tried with several, they are directly from my GoPro. Let me try from command line

Comment: I'm afraid the errors is the same as above even when matching the bitrate of the video to the command line config. I think I may have to look at another solution to trim these videos as FFMPEG is not working. Does anyone have any suggestions to other opensource software I can use?